# Asymptotic behavior of integral in general

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose $f(x,y) \sim g(x)$ as $y \to c$ and the integral $\int_a^bg(x)dx$ may be improper but convergent.

**Then is it true that $\int_a^bf(x,y)dx \sim \int_a^b g(x)dx$ as $y \to c$?**

I first tried to prove this when asymptotic behavior is uniform.  There is $\delta$ such that $|\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)} -1| < \epsilon$ for $|y-c| < \delta$ for all $x$. Then

$$|\int_a^bf(x,y)dx - \int_a^bg(x)dx| \leq \int_a^b|\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)} - 1||g(x)|dx \leq \epsilon\int_a^b|g(x)|dx $$

but I can't make any conclusions yet since it is not assumed that $\int_a^b|g(x)|dx$ is absolutely convergent.

Also if the asymptotic behavior of $f$ is not uniform then is the result still true? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Your question involves interchanging limits, which is not usually possible (without further conditions). You are really asking if
$$\lim_{y\to c}f(x,y) = g(x) \;\text{implies}\; \lim_{y\to c} \int_a^b f(x,y)\,dx = \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$$
A quick search on this site will give you plenty of related answers.

Comment: Look up the Dominated Convergence Theorem.